# mySQL - Count and SUM on same line

Tags: mysql

I have 2 tables - `Transaction` and `TransactionEntry`.  `Transaction` contains the time and `TransactionEntry` contains the item(s) sold.

One `Transaction` can have many `TransactionEntry`

I want to find all the `TransactionEntry.ItemID`'s within 2 dates and SUM the `TransactionEntry.Quantity`.  Then GROUP BY `TransactionEntry.ItemID`.

The code for this works and gives the expected result:

```
SELECT TransactionEntry.ItemID AS iID, SUM(TransactionEntry.Quantity)
FROM Transaction INNER JOIN TransactionEntry ON TransactionEntry.TransactionNumber = Transaction.TransactionNumber
WHERE Transaction.Time > '2015-07-27 00:00:00' AND Transaction.Time < '2015-08-02 23:59:59'
GROUP BY TransactionEntry.ItemID
ORDER BY SUM(TransactionEntry.Quantity) DESC
```

Not sure how to create a table so I drew the example haha:

```
 -----------------
| iID   | SUM(T.. |
|-----------------| 
| 30419 | 58      |
| 30420 | 50      |
| 55416 | 36      |
| ...   | ...     |
 -----------------
```

My problem is that I want a 3rd column, which tells me how many Transactions make up the SUM.  Using the example above, iID 30419 sold 58 times but that may have been to 58 different people or to just 1 person.  I want to know this.

The following SQL works:

```
SELECT COUNT(TransactionEntry.ID) 
FROM Transaction INNER JOIN TransactionEntry ON TransactionEntry.TransactionNumber = Transaction.TransactionNumber 
WHERE Transaction.Time > '2015-07-27 00:00:00' AND Transaction.Time < '2015-08-02 23:59:59' AND TransactionEntry.ItemID = 10791
```

But I'm unsure how to combine the 2, if that makes sense.

I have tried the following but it times out:

```
SELECT TransactionEntry.ItemID AS iID, SUM(TransactionEntry.Quantity), (SELECT COUNT(TransactionEntry.ID) FROM Transaction INNER JOIN TransactionEntry ON TransactionEntry.TransactionNumber = Transaction.TransactionNumber WHERE Transaction.Time > '2015-07-27 00:00:00' AND Transaction.Time < '2015-08-02 23:59:59' AND TransactionEntry.ItemID = iID) AS C
FROM Transaction INNER JOIN TransactionEntry ON TransactionEntry.TransactionNumber = Transaction.TransactionNumber
WHERE Transaction.Time > '2015-07-27 00:00:00' AND Transaction.Time < '2015-08-02 23:59:59'
GROUP BY TransactionEntry.ItemID
ORDER BY SUM(TransactionEntry.Quantity) DESC
```

Is what I'm after possible?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try this one:

```
SELECT T.ItemID
    , SUM(TE.Quantity)
    , COUNT(TE.ID) 
    FROM Transaction T
    INNER JOIN TransactionEntry TE ON TE.TransactionNumber = T.TransactionNumber
    WHERE T.Time BETWEEN '2015-07-27 00:00:00' AND '2015-08-02 23:59:59'
    GROUP BY T.ItemID
```

Comment: Wow that works! (I had to change T.ItemID to just ItemID though) I didn't realise you could name a table to shorten it either.  Thats awesome! Thanks!

Comment: No problem mate. That's table aliasing, saves you time in writing queries ;)